# Parts of my character mesh are displaying too brightly

Tags: mesh, rigging, lighting

I have modelled and rigged a few characters for an animation I'm working on but I've encountered a problem where the light in a scene seems to 'snake' into the mouth and causes it to be way too illuminated.
[image: Too much light in the dim room]

I say ‘snake’ because I know that the light sources that are causing the illumination are the three lamps I have in the scene positioned above the character at a slight offset, but when I have used an object to block out the light, the inside of the mouth is still illuminated, it’s like the light is ignoring the head of the character and passing straight through just to illuminate the mouth.
[image: The whole scene, three point lights are used with the power of 20 W]

The mesh is fine, all normals are in the right orientation, there are no gaps etc. But still the light is determined to get inside the mouth. I have a feeling that the keyframes or armature I have attached to the character mesh have something to do with it but I really don’t have a clue.
I just need to know a way to cast a shadow inside the mouth or block out the light inside the mouth without it affecting the rest of the scene.

[image: Even with a large block to obscure the light, the mouth is still illuminated to the same intensity]

[image: normal orientation for the face]

Comment: Hello, maybe you've used an Emission shader? Please share your head object

Comment: @moonboots do you mean for the materials? The skin is just a principled BSDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eevee as the rendering engine, try checking the Ambient Occlusion option and you can also adjust the values in the Shadows section. Illuminated mouths are a rather common issue with renderers that don't use true raytracing, like Eevee. Alternatively you can switch to Cycles which should give you much more realistic results, but might be slower to render.
[image]

Comment: @ vintagepotato This is true, but I am using Cycles as my current rendering engine and still getting this problem, infact it only occurs when using Cycles. (I should have been specific about this in the original post)

Comment: @Fahrenheit I noticed your Point Light Settings has "Cast Shadows" unchecked. That might be what's causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot I did this earlier for my lamp shades! The problem has been fixed